Effects of Localized Medium Changes on Field Propagation
I've studied various theories related to fields. These theories often include equations describing how the activity of a source is transmitted to other locations. The properties of the medium influence this propagation.
I'm wondering if there are theories that address the following scenario: If the properties of the medium change at a specific point, how would this affect the propagation results?
To illustrate my question more concretely, let me provide an example from electrostatics:
In electrostatics, the electric potential satisfies Poisson's equation:
$$\nabla^2\phi = -\rho /\epsilon,$$
where $\epsilon$ is the dielectric constant of the medium, which can vary with position. Given specific boundary conditions and charge distribution, we can solve for the electric potential distribution.
Now, let's consider a scenario where the dielectric constant suddenly changes at a particular location in the medium. We can represent this as
$$\epsilon \to \epsilon + C \delta (r-r_0)$$
where $C$ is a constant and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function.
My question is: How can we calculate the change in the electric potential distribution caused by this sudden change in the dielectric constant?
This example demonstrates the type of problem I'm interested in, where a localized change in the medium's properties affects the field distribution. I'm curious about the mathematical techniques and physical insights used to approach such problems, not just in electrostatics but in other areas of physics as well.
